# How to run Gradle JAR against local dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

When I run `gradle clean jar` it pulls down all my executable JAR's dependencies under `~/.gradle` and then creates my JAR.

I am then having to jump through *serious* hoops to run the JAR locally:

1. First I create a `lib` directory in the same folder as the newly-created JAR
2. Then I have to cherry pick all of my project's transitive dependencies (there are lots) out from `~/.gradle` and copy them to `lib`
3. Then I run from the command-line `java -jar myapp.jar -cp "lib/*"`

Every time my dependencies change (new code is added, etc.) I have to go through this process, and it makes me wonder if there is a more elegant way to run your Gradle-built apps locally.

Comment: You need a gradle `fatjar` or `shadow` plugin. Google for it.

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) but I **abhor** the idea of hodge-podging 70+ JARs into one giant fat JAR. There **must** be a way to do this without having to go that route...

Comment: Ok, understood. You may also try gradle distribution or application plugin. Read for details: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html or http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html

Comment: Thanks again @Opal (+1) - with the application plugin, will it also include `compile` dependencies or just `runtime`? I ask because I currently have all my dependencies declared as `compile` and am wondering what I would need to do (if anything) to get them added to the classpath when using the application plugin. Thanks again!

Comment: No sure really. You need to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with the `application` plugin. It turns out that Gradle considers `compile` dependencies a subset of `runtime` so I didn't need to change any dependency scopes.  I can now just issue `gradle run` and it runs my app beautifully.

Comment: That makes sense if you think about it - you need all the compile-time dependencies in order to run but not necessarily the runtime dependencies in order to compile.